# Is there a plug-in to have Firefox Download Manager save files with the modified time?

Tags: firefox, download-manager

I would like Firefox to automatically update the modified time of a downloaded file to the modified time indicated in the HTTP headers. This would allow me to more easily determine when a particular download was updated (and not just when the bytes were transmitted to my machine).

I've searched and find no such plug-in.

Is there a reason why Firefox would not enact this behavior by default?

Is there a plug-in or other download manager that has this capability?

Comment: It shouldn't be enabled by default, because often you need to compare the modified time to a file you already have to see which is newer. The file you already have might be a system file, or obtained via some other source (eg, a cd) so adjusting the modified time would prevent this use.

Comment: I don't understand the comment. Which use is prevented, and why is it better for the downloaded file to be designated as "modified" when it was downloaded instead of when the content was last changed (presumably the modified time provided by the server)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201)** saves the modified-time correctly.
It also has many other good features -- I hardly ever use the regular download method.